# Улетели кнопки свайпера на самый верх макета, как это можно исправить?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

```js
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  // Optional parameters
  direction: 'vertical',
  loop: true,

  // If we need pagination
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
  },

  // Navigation arrows
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },

  // And if we need scrollbar
  scrollbar: {
    el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
  },
});
```

```css
.slider__container{
height: 500px;

}
```

```html
<div class="slider__container">
  <div class="slider__box">

<!-- Slider main container -->
<div class="swiper-container">
  <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <!-- Slides -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
  </div>
  <!-- If we need pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

</div>


  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Здесь должен быть кнопки слайдера]
[image: Самый вверх макета куда улетели кнопки слайдера]

Comment: Привет! Предлагаю проинспектировать в браузере элементы веб страницы, есть предположение что есть какие то стили которые влияют на позиционирование этих дотов слайдера...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если посмотрите [документацию Swiper](https://swiperjs.com/get-started#add-swiper-html-layout), то обратите внимаение, что всё начинается с элемента `.swiper`, потом идёт `.swipper-wrapper` в него уже добавляют слайды `.swiper-slide`.

Суть в том, что кнопки позиционируются при помощи `position: absolute;` и кнопки "улетели" т.к. у вашего `.swiper-container` отсутствует правило `position: relative`, которым обладает удалённый `.swiper`.

Советую оставить класс `.swiper` и добавить свой `.swiper-container` вторым классом:

```js
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
  // Optional parameters
  direction: 'vertical',
  loop: true,

  // If we need pagination
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
  },

  // Navigation arrows
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },

  // And if we need scrollbar
  scrollbar: {
    el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
  },
});
```

```css
@import url(https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css);

.swiper.swiper-container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
}

.swiper.swiper-container .swiper-slide {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- Slider main container -->
<div class="swiper swiper-container">
  <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <!-- Slides -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
  </div>
  <!-- If we need pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

  <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

  <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
  <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
</div>
```